# Can a Skype bot in Group initialize a group call?

Tags: botframework, bots, skype, skypedeveloper, skype-bots

I wanted to develop a Skype bot which is able to initialize a group call at a particular time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Check out Microsoft Azure documentation, starting with "[Conduct audio calls with Skype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-audio-calls?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)"